# Fluidly vertically expanding DIV or TEXTAREA

Tags: css, html, textarea, fluid-layout

I want a textarea to take up as much vertical space as possible without overlapping any other visual elements.  Obviously different screens / devices are different heights so I need the solution to be fluid (I think that's the right term).

The other questions I've looked at don't involve textareas, instead using (child) DIVs whose content is already determined.  I don't need the textarea to expand dynamically to fit it's content, I just want it to be as tall as possible but without obscuring any other elements.

I've collected together parts of answers to similar questions but can't quite make it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/wa5zU/

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}
p {
    text-align:justify
}
textarea {
    resize:vertical;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.vexpand {
    border:1px solid blue
}
.vexpand {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:90%;
    height:auto
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Some content of variable length / height to fill the top portion of the screen</h2>

<p>Either: 1) make the blue-bordered DIV expand fluidly to fill this gap or 2) make the textarea expand to achieve the same effect</p>
<div class="vexpand">
    <div>One line of content related to the textarea that must be kept with the textarea</div>
    <textarea rows=5 cols=10>I have heard that textareas need valid rows and cols attributes in order to respond correctly to height and width css</textarea>
</div>
```

This attempt is based on `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` assuming that the DIV can be expanded upwards.  I did it this way because the content above the DIV/TEXTAREA is variable so couldn't find an elegant and robust way to measure from the `top`.

There is a line of content related to the textarea that must be kept with the textarea, hence encapsulating this content and the textarea in a `div`.  Ideally I would prefer that content to stay above the textarea.

Things I've tried / seen in related questions:

- `position:absolute` and conflicting absolute position
- setting the `height` of `body` and `html` to 100% so that CSS can perform calculations
- using `height:auto` or `height:100%` on the wrapper div `.vexpand` or the `textarea`
- setting the `cols` and `rows` attributes on the `textarea` so that it responds to `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/wa5zU/2/

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    text-align:justify
}
*
{
   box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;   
}

textarea {
    resize:vertical;
    height: calc(100% - 20px) ;
    width:100%;      
}

.text-content
{
    height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.editor
{
  height: 20%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I want the textarea's div ('.editor' in your answer) to fill all the vertical space from the line ending '2) make the textarea expand to achieve the same effect' down to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: So you want the textarea to always start bejond the end of the last paragraph of the document?

Comment: you will always have to set the height of the elements if you don't want to risk them to be overlapping. At least in percentage... Or did i get you totaly wrong? I guess I understood correct... I stay with > You will have to define a height of both elements. You may also use min/max-height to prevent unwanted effects.

If you really can not know the height of the content, you will have to use Javascript to mesure. But this will also be bad if the content is higher than the bodys 100% height.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've managed to be able to fix the content at the top of the page so that I can use your calc() css suggestion.